# How could I change an image inside of a ListView?

Tags: android, image, listview

I read another posts and I did not find a solution for me. I created a custom **ListView**. Each and every item of the this list is complex-item, containing **ImageView** plus two **TextViews**. After the adapter is applied and the list is filled up, I want to change the image inside the **ImageView**, but I want that to happen not on click event.

```
private class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

    private List<RSSItem> items;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<RSSItem> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        RSSItem item = items.get(position);
        if (item != null) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            TextView description = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            if (image != null) {
                Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
                image.setTag(item.getImageURL());
                image.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
            }
            if (title != null) {
                title.setText(item.getTitle());
            }
            if (description != null) {
                description.setText(item.toString());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

I tried to get Context, but then I don't know how to access the correct **ImageView**.
I appreciate any help!

Comment: and you want to change it based on what condition?

Comment: after an **AsyncTask** has finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a field to your `RSSItem` class that tells the adapter which image to display. In your `AsyncTask.onPostExecute` method change that value and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged` method of the `ArrayAdapter`.

Your `getView()` override should use the value you put in your RSSItem to choose which image to display. It will be called again for each item when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Lazy loading of images inside your ArrayAdapter**

There's great tutorials online that shows full code examples on how to do this, and also include caching so you don't download images more than once.

- http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/

Additionally the SHELVES android application, free open source app written by one of the google engineers which also has examples of multi-threading, lazy loading and caching of images for an arrayadapter.  I **highly** recommend that you read through this code.

- http://code.google.com/p/shelves/

Answer (score 1):

You could try this if you want to change the imageview from outside of the adapter's getView() function.

```
List<View> listOfViews = new ArrayList<View>();
listView1.reclaimViews(listOfViews);
for (View v : listOfViews)
{
    ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
    image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```